# How to make animated vectors start on their own in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, svg, android-jetpack-compose

The problem i have is that i can render SVGs but i can't make them automatically start, i've seen examples where with the onclick method i could start the svg but i'd need it to automatically start without any user action, is it possible?

I used this documentation but it only rembers the svg https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/resources#animated-vector-drawables

Note:
When i render the SVG in its XML, the animation works fine without any problem.

Comment: Maybe you could add codes you have tried?

Comment: Could you try this answer and see if it works? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/67190790/13083841

Comment: I had to use the Launched Effect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use **LaunchedEffect** right after the view like that:

```
val image = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(R.drawable.animated_vector)
var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Icon(
    painter = rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(image, atEnd),
    contentDescription = null // decorative element
)

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    //delay(200)
    //Custom delay could be here if needed
    atEnd = true
}
```